# Clicking on new test case is not doing anything for for AzureDevOPS 2019

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have recently installed Azure Devops 2019.

[image]

When I go to Test Plans and click New test case it's not doing anything for me.

Did anyone face similar issue?

Comment: Which edition of Azure DevOps 2019 do you use? Please go to Administration Console -- Application Tier to get the edition of your server.

Comment: I am using 17.143.28912.1 (AzureDevOps2019.0.1)

Comment: Please try to upgrade to latest AzureDevOps2019.Update1.1, to see whether the issue persists.

Comment: Do you have sufficient permission to do this? Did you get any error in trace log from F12. Could you share the related log info here?

Comment: I am getting below error in trace log from F12 ""$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"VS402325: Work item type category Microsoft.TestCaseCategory does not exist in project or you do not have access to it.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.Metadata.WorkItemTypeCategoryNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server","typeKey":"WorkItemTypeCategoryNotFoundException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3200}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgrade my Azure DevOps 2019 to the latest edition 17.153.29522.3 (AzureDevOps2019.Update1.1), and tested with both Chrome and Edge, but couldn't reproduce your issue.

I'd like to suggest you upgrade your server to the latest edition and test in other browsers.